# How to extract element from array with regex?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I would like to extract the first url from the array listed below. 
I  want to use Python3 with regular expressions, but I can't match the string.

This is what I tried

```
import pandas as pd
import re


reg = "\['\S*"


myDataFrame = pd.read_csv('Refactored_Test_1.csv')

imageColumn = myDataFrame.loc[:,"image"]
print(imageColumn)

for element  in imageColumn: 
    print(element)

['https://ui.assets-asda.com/dm/asdagroceries/8000500217078_T1?defaultImage=asdagroceries/noImage&resMode=sharp2&id=nHnSx1&fmt=jpg&fit=constrain,1&wid=188&hei=188', 'https://ui.assets-asda.com/dm/asdagroceries/8000500217078_T2?defaultImage=asdagroceries/noImage&resMode=sharp2&id=PS8Sl2&fmt=jpg&fit=constrain,1&wid=188&hei=188']
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean `\['(\S+)'` https://regex101.com/r/CxZ8NX/1 Or with lookarounds `(?<=\[')\S+(?=')` https://regex101.com/r/FeUu6L/1

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a capturing group and repeat the non whitespace char 1+ more times and match the `'` that comes after it.

```
\['(\S+)'
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CxZ8NX/1)

If you want a match only, you could use lookarounds:

```
(?<=\[')\S+(?=')
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FeUu6L/1)

Comment: And to extract it, it should be? ```imageColumn = imageColumn.str.extract(r'\['(\S+)')```

Comment: Like that I think you have to escape the quote `r'\[\'(\S+)'`

Comment: I get "unexpected character after line error" ```imageColumn = imageColumn.str.extract(r'(?<=\[')\S+(?=')')```

Comment: Try escaping both single quotes `imageColumn = imageColumn.str.extract(r'(?<=\[\')\S+(?=\')')`